# Import a module in Python

Tags: python

I have an improperly packaged Python module. It only has `__init__.py` file in the directory. This file defines the class that I wish to use. What would be the best way to use it as a module in my script?

** EDIT **

There was a period (.) in the the name of the folder. So the methods suggested here were not working. It works fine if I rename the folder to have a valid name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not improper. It's a package.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

```
package/
    __init__.py
yourmodule.py
```

In yourmodule.py, you can do either of the following:

```
import package
x = package.ClassName()
```

Or:

```
from package import ClassName
x = ClassName()
```

Comment: There was a period in the name of the module's folder, so it was throwing an error. It works fine if I rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Put `__init__.py` into directory `my_module`, make sure `my_module` is in `sys.path`, and then `from my_module import WHAT_EVER_YOU_WANT`

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily improperly packaged. You should be able to do `from package import X` just like you would normally. `__init__.py` files are modules just like any other `.py` file, they just have some special semantics as to how they are evaluated in addition to the normal usage, and are basically aliased to the package name.